# Allowing persistence for alternative selections in grouped_collection_select multi-select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, persistence, jquery-chosen

I have a three tiered cascading multiple selection menu. The tiers are State, City and Location. Upon selecting a State, then City a user can select multiple Locations for example where the user has chosen to select `1235 Ok Drive` and `5678 Drive dr`:

[image]

Afterwards,a user may choose to select another city and state, as well as another location, in this case `1 at&t way`:

[image]

However, as the user then saves, Active record does not persist the previous selections of `1235 Ok Drive` and `5678 Drive dr` but instead only keeps with the most recent selections, in this case `1 at&t way`

Building the menus:

```
    State:
    <%= f.collection_select :id, State.order(:state), :id, :state %>

    City:
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :city_ids, State.order(:state), :cities, :state, :id, :city_whole %>

    Location:
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:location_ids, City.order(:city), :locations, :city_whole, :id, :address,{}, {multiple: true}) %>
```

and CoffeeScript:

```
jQuery ->

# For the State to City dynamic menu
  cities = $('#campaign_city_ids').html()
  console.log(cities)
  $('#campaign_id').change ->
    state = $('#campaign_id :selected').text()
    options = $(cities).filter("optgroup[label='#{state}']").html()
    console.log(options)
    if options
      $('#campaign_city_ids').html(options);
    else
      $('#campaign_city_ids').empty();

# For the City to lcoation dynamic menu
  locations = $('#campaign_location_ids').html()
  console.log(locations)
  $('#campaign_city_ids').change ->
    city = $('#campaign_city_ids :selected').text()
    city_option = $(locations).filter("optgroup[label='#{city}']").html()
    console.log(city_option)
    if city_option
      $('#campaign_location_ids').html(city_option).trigger('chosen:updated').chosen();
    else
      $('#campaign_location_ids').empty();
```

How can I make all selections persist and stay selected even as the user chooses other options?